# How to know inside binary about the symlink through which it is invoked?

Tags: linux, symlink

Suppose I have multiple symlink for a binary created, which was known before the binary was created and also the symlink name is also known.
I want to differentiate the call this binary will do depending on which symlink invoked it.
For an example, a and b symlinks points to binary math. when a is executed, then it prints "a". when invoked via b, then it prints "b". when math binary is executed, it print "default".

I am trying for same binary to be invoked via symlink.
The binary could be written in any language. So please advise on this as well.

Comment: Bash, whose `sh` compatibility mode is enabled or disabled depending on how the shell was invoked (as `sh` symlink or `bash`), just uses `argv[0]`: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/shell.c?id=ddf3f643cb9b9a2ca8e6d996c605e4332204874c#n1736

Comment: Note, that this approach is rather hacky, as there are no strict guaranties about `argv[0]` - its value is pretty conventional, so it is not a bulletproof way to determine that your binary is launched via symlink.